# Diff between files in same directory structure in linux

Tags: linux, file

I have two directories that contains the same directory structure, also directory names are same (possibly different number of files) and how can I find out the differences between all the file contents and files in Linux?

Here is an example

```
\dir1
  \subdir1
    \file1
  \subdir2
    \file2
    \file3


dir2
  \subdir1
    \file1
  \subdir2
    \file2
    \file3
    \file4
```

The content of file1 in dir1 and file1 in dir2 are different. The content of file2 in dir1 and file2 in dir2 are different. I can use

```
$diff dir1\subdir1\file1 dir2\subdir1\file1
$diff dir1\subdir1\file2 dir2\subdir1\file2
```

But I have to manually do the diff for each file. I would like to have an automatic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to list the files being different, try:

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2
```

If you want to list the difference inside each file, remove the `q`:

```
diff -r dir1 dir2
```